# Variance of A Biased Coin

Tags: probability, statistical-mechanics

I was working a statistical mechanics's problem on a biased coin to find the variance of the probability of getting heads on $N$ throws:

> When a biased coin is flipped the outcome is heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1 − p$. If this coin is flipped $N$ times, the probability that the total number of heads is $n$ is:
>   $$p(n)=\begin{pmatrix} N\\
> n \\
> \end{pmatrix}p^n(1-p)^{N-n}$$
>
> The most likely value of $n$ is $n = pN$, but there are fluctuations about
>   this most likely value.
>   Denote $n = Np + s$, and suppose that $N \gg 1$. In this limit, $p(n)$, regarded as a function of $s$, approaches a Gaussian with mean zero and some variance $\sigma^2_p$; hence,
>
> given
>
> $$\ln p(n)= \text{constant}-\frac{s^2}{2\sigma^2_p}+O(s^4) \tag 1$$
>
> where “constant” means a term independent of $s$. Calculate $\sigma^2_p$ using the Stirling approximation and the approximations $s \ll pN$ and $s \ll (1−p)N.$

I have worked the standard way, and got the correct answer $\sigma^2_p=Np(1-p)$. However, there is another quicker way to do this:

> observe $(1)$ and for a large $N$ we have: $$\partial_n^2\ln p(n)=-\dfrac 1 {2\sigma^2}$$
>
> from the left hand side we have:
>
> $$\partial_n^2 \ln p(n) \approx \ln p(n+1)-\ln p(n)- \ln p(n) + \ln p(n-1) = \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2_p}$$
>
> after some work, then we have: $\sigma^2_p= \frac{n(N-n)}{N}$

Then here comes what I don't understand :

> This expression should be evaluated at $n = pN$,
>
> hence $\sigma^2_p=Np(1-p)$

Why this expression should be evaluated at $n = pN$? This is very unclear to me.

Comment: I think the idea is this: the first equality in your second quote box should actually be $\partial_n^2 \ln p(n)=-1/2\sigma^2_p+O(s^2)$. In order to get the higher order $O(s^2)$ terms to disappear, you need to plug in $s=0$, which is equivalent to plugging in $n = nP$.

Comment: Just for the record, this is [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with expectation or mean $E[X]=np$ and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) $Var[X]=np(1-p)$